# ASP.Net VB string to date based on format used in string

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, date

I'm using a JavaScript datepicker that gives me the selected date based on the language. So when the language is Dutch I get an output like 21-09-2017 (dd-mm-yyyy) And for English 21/09/2017.

When I want to cast these Strings to Dates (CDate) I get a problem with the format. Day = Month or Month = Day. What is the best way to make a Date from a string based on the format used in the string?

A solution would be to write a function for each specific culture to handle the dates but i'm guessing there is a default function in .Net??

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DateTime.ParseExact** to get what you want as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can provide the format like so:

```
dateString = "15/06/2008 08:30" //Your Date time
format = "g" //General Fromat
provider = New CultureInfo("fr-FR") //French
result = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider) //Parsed Result
```

*this will result in: 6/15/2008 8:30:00 AM*

This or course only works if you know the culture. Also you may want to check out the Date Time Format Strings found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(String).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

OR

```
DateTime.ParseExact(String, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```